# Screen froze and display garbled after booting Ubuntu and other distros

Tags: system-installation, display, hardware-acceleration

My pc is freezing and screen flickering when I boot Ubuntu or any other distro.
Today I successfully installed Android x86 with the option "no hardware acceleration" so my question is there a option of no hardware acceleration in Ubuntu or any other distros?

Comment: We only support Ubuntu and official flavors, but are you asking about the 'nomodeset' option?  (*this is possibly what your Android x86 option enables as a boot parameter* https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions)

Comment: It's very likely you need to install graphics drivers. Please post hardware specifications.